# Stop Gmail and Google Calendar from replacing URL's titles

Tags: gmail, google-calendar, google, copy-paste

From about 2-3 weeks or so Gmail and Google Calendar (and probably many more) has enabled a "helpful" feature of replacing URL with corresponding webpage's title, when those pasting URL.

Is there any way to prevent this? I.e. If I paste `https://onezeronull.com/2021/06/22/force-microsoft-edge-to-safe-images-with-jpg-instead-of-jfif-extension/`, I want to see *exactly* this text / URLs (linked or not) and not this instead:

[image]

This happens in Gmail and in Google Calendar, as far as I noticed, but most likely in any editor-like field in any Google-like product.

The only way that I found so far to prevent this is to paste everything with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> which enforces *paste as plain text* functionality. But, I keep forgetting about this and another "helpful" feature from Google becomes really annoying.

Is there any other way (configuration switch, extension etc.) to stop that behaviour?